# Very strange iframe event behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

This question has me completely stumped. Since it's in a browser extension, I can't post my code.

The issue is apparently that mouse events inside the iframe (hovering over a link, over text, selecting...) are off by about 200px, this includes right clicks as shown in this screenshot:

[image: The red dot is the actual mouseclick location]

The red dot is the actual mouseclick location. Again, since this is an extension (I'm actually doing the JS part in Tampermonkey, it's easier) I can't try it out in other browsers so it might just be chrome.

The iframe is to contain third-party dynamically loaded content so I can't use a div or other element. It's also reused and is dynamically inserted on load.

This also doesn't happen the first time content is inserted instead it takes a few "cycles" to appear.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was apparently a Chrome bug, albeit a strange one. I started having other issues so I reinstalled Chrome and upgraded to Windows 8 (I was planning to anyway), the bug seems to have gone away.

**EDIT:** It just came back, it turns out that the issue was that I was using `-webkit-transform: scale()` to show and hide the frame with a transition, removing this fixes the issue.

So, to all those with iframe mouse event issues in Chrome/WebKit: check all of your transforms and any CSS3 effects, try removing them one at a time.